# Python sockets how to add multiple clients and send bytes to each client

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make it so multiple clients can connect to my server and communicate with each other. At the moment I load up the server and connect the client and I can send messages to the server I can also connect another client but when i send messages from a client i want it to go to the other client so they can see it. At the moment all it does is send it to the server can anyone help. Here is my code so far:

```
import socket
import threading
import select
import time
from queue import Queue


all_connections = []
all_address = []


HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = '!DISCONNECT'



server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn, addr,):
    print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.')

connected = True
while connected:
    msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        if '[SERVER]' in msg:
            print('')
        else:    
            print(f'[{addr}] {msg}')
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False
                print(f'[{addr}] has disconnected')

    
            
conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f'[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}')
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        conn.send("Welcome to server!".encode(FORMAT))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f'[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() -1}')

    


print('[STARTING] server is starting...')
start()
```

Comment: Keep a global list of all the accepted sockets.  When you receive something, you can broadcast to the whole list.  Remember to remove a socket when it disconnects.

Comment: Remember that Python has a "socketserver" module in its standard library.  If you need to get trickier than that, it's time to look into Twisted, which is the best network module for Python, in my opinion.